# How Best to Change the Symfony Front-End Controller

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I created a new Symfony project, without using the installer, according to the instructions here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#creating-symfony-applications-without-the-installer.

I accepted all the defaults, including the demo bundle, `AcmeWebBundle`.

I configured an Apache virtual host doc-rooted at the new project and restarted the web server.  I would like to access the application via "http://virtualhost/" (ie, without explicitly calling the front-end controller `app.php` or `app_dev.php`).

Installed with the project was a `.htaccess` file that sets the `DirectoryIndex` to `app.php`.  I would like to use the developer environment for development, but (long story short) it seems the only way to do this is by manually editing the `.htaccess` file - both the `DirectoryIndex` setting, plus a few `mod_rewrite` directives.

Is there a simpler way to switch between environments/controllers without having to edit the `.htaccess` file?  For bonus points, I had to figure this out by trial and error - was this explained in the documentation someplace that I missed?

Thanks, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} \.dev$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you use host that ends on `.dev` you will work with dev-environment.

For example you can use `virtualhost` as prod-env host and `virtualhost.dev` as dev-env host.